# Importing components and css separately in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, import, components

I just got started with vue.js and there is one concept that is quite confusing, still.

What's the difference between importing a vue.js "component" and a css file?

Taking for example `bootstrap` and `vue-bootstrap`. Do I need both? Just one? Which?

To me, it seems like if I want to be able to use bootstrap as a vue component like `<b-link>` I need to import the `vue-bootstrap`. If I want to use it in a regular html tag then I also need to import the `.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at `bootstrap-vue` as a bunch of functional components someone wrote to wrap around `bootstrap` styling (from what I make of it). You only have to import the `bootstrap-vue` `npm` package, then tell `Vue` to use it (`Vue` will use the `bootstrap-vue` package as a plugin by way of `Vue.use()`)

That gives you access to things like `<b-link>`, etc.. but you still have to import the `.css` files..

This is where you need the original `bootstrap.css` file, plus the `bootstrap-vue.css` file, in order to get the appropriate styling on the imported `<b-*>` components.. (that you imported above).

Therefore, your entry point should look like this at the end of the day:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

You can still use regular classes to style the custom components, but it is important to note these `<b-*>` components are different than regular HTML elements. They come with properties and certain options that allow you to style them how you would like.

[Here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button/#button-sizing) is an example of using regular classes on a component..

Instead of doing something like `<button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>` you would do: `<b-button variant="success">Button</b-button>`

You can read more on how `bootstrap-vue` handles color variants, etc [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/color-variants/#color-variants-and-css-class-mapping) - all in all, I would read their documentation to get a better grasp of it.